# how to match only two letters after underscore regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write regex that matches an underscore and exactly 2 letters at the end of the word.

For example, in `name_lang_en` it should match `_en` but in `opening_time` or `closing_time` it should not match anything.

I tried something like this but it didn't work

```
[^_]+$
```

Comment: What you tried was to match `'` followed by one or more characters other than underscore (`[^_]+`) at the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "I tried something like this but it didn't work" - **what does this mean**? What is the **specific thing** that you tried (not "something like", but a proper [mre], with actual Python code and not just the contents of a regex)? **What happened** when you tried that, and **how is that different** from what you wanted to happen?

Comment: `_[A-Za-z]{2}\b` you can use this to match two letters after underscore.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use \S for non-space (or more specific pattern for what you mean with "letter" but `[^_]` would also match space which is no good), {2} to say exactly two of them, then \b to match the (end of) word boundary:

```
r"_\S{2}\b"
```